# Composer MPDF Upgrade doesn't actually do anything

Tags: php, composer-php, mpdf

I just upgraded to PHP 7.4 and encountered the curly braces problem with a number of third party PHP applications. It was easy enough to upgrade them until I hit MPDF which was installed using Composer.

I've spend a day on it so far and I've finally reached the point where if I run ...

```
composer.phar require mpdf/mpdf dev-php8-support
```

Composer *says* it's upgraded MPDF, but the curly braces error has not been fixed and investigation shows that in actuality, none of the files in the /vendor/mpdf/mdpf folder have changed.

Composer appears to have done nothing.

I've run out of ideas as to how to get this to work.

While the official MPDF page has an installation guide it doesn't even even mention upgrading.

Does anyone have any clues as to what might be going ? ... or perhaps even better - how to just download and replace the PHP  files? (which would be infinitely simpler than messing around with an intermediate software package just to copy a few files onto a server)

EDIT: Just to prove that composer isn't actually doing anything I deleted the /vendor/mpdf folder and ran

```
composer.phar require mpdf/mpdf
```

again and a new /vendor/mpdf folder wasn't created.

Comment: composer.lock says "name": "mpdf/mpdf",
            "version": "v8.1.1",

Comment: composer.json says  "require": {
        "mpdf/mpdf": "^8.1"
    }

Comment: Okay ... I've found the files that composer is installing.

it's putting them in /vendor/vendor/mpdf/ instead of just /vendor/mpdf/

Hmmmm .... now to work out how to it from stop doing that!

Comment: I moved composer.phar up one directory level and it now places the php scripts in the correct place. Mpdf appears to now be working with PHP 7.4. Phew! There's a day of my life I won't get back!

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

1. Reinstall Composer
2. Completely Uninstall MPDF
3. Re-install MPDF
   oh and ...
4. Pray that I never have to upgrade anything via Composer again.